# Sugar ORM Android application loses persistent object's id field when navigating to new screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sugarorm

I have a Sugar ORM persistent object declared as follows:

```
public class Trx extends SugarRecord implements Serializable {
...
}
```

**Note that** when you extend SugarRecord, you inherit an **id** field used to uniquely identify your persistent object.

When navigating from my application's master view to it's detail view, I create the intent/activity as follows:

```
Trx selectedItem = (Trx)trxList.getItemAtPosition(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(this,TransactionViewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(CommonThings.CURRENT_TRX_KEY,selectedItem);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the detail view, I'm retrieving the current item (in the onCreate()) as follows:

```
trx = (Trx) getIntent().getExtras().get(CommonThings.CURRENT_TRX_KEY);
```

My problem is thus: after fetching the item out of "extras" and debugging it, the id field is missing.

I can ofcourse do a workaround that entails passing the id of my object as the "extra" and then hitting the database again once I'm in the new activity, but I'd like to know why the above won't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by changing my persistent objects to use Sugar annotations instead of extending SugarRecord i.e.

from:

```
public class Trx extends SugarRecord implements Serializable {
...
}
```

to:

```
@Table
public class Trx implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
...
}
```

This resolves my issue with the missing id field